# Apple password not being accepted

Tags: password

Trying to install a settings update on my iPad but it won't accept my password.
I have tried resetting password but it still won't accept it
I'm afraid I'm a bit of a dinosaur

Comment: Iforgot.apple.com

Comment: or clickable - https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 4):

Visit https://iforgot.apple.com to reset your password with Apple ID:

> ### Reset your password
>
> You can change or reset the password for your Apple ID account by providing some information.